# Is SQL Injection possible after filtering " and /?

Tags: sql-injection

I'm aiming at building dynamic SQL queries that modify columns. The DBMS doesn't allow parameters to be there, so I can't escape identifier using more robust methods.

To be clearer, using `?` or `$1` is not permitted with identifiers, just with values, and my need is to use dynamic identifiers.

One approach I though is to completely filter out the double quotes and backslash characters from any identifier, and then quote them, so if an identifier is like `my"field\` it becomes `"myfield"`.

I did some research, but it's not clear if completely filtering out these  characters (or like "[]" for non-standard implementations like MSSQL) can avoid any "execution of bad stuff" when parsing the string. Is there something else I should look for?

Thanks

Comment: There's always more "bad stuff" than your filter can handle.

Comment: That's the point, I have no idea if strange unicode sequences or malformed strings can harm the query or not. From the standpoint of a parser, if no escape sequences are found, there should be no risk, am I wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with using Binds?

Comment: Why don't you show relevant parts of your code?

Comment: If by Binds you mean like "WHERE id = ?", it's because identifiers are not accepted as them. My need is to set dynamically field names. Code doesn't really seem relevant, though I could write an example, if needed. This is more about the parsing of strings